# Probability of first ball is red or second ball is red

Tags: probability, combinations

> A bag contains $2$ red and $6$ black balls. Two balls are drawn in succession without replacement from a bag. Then find the probability that the first  ball is red or the second ball is red.

What I have tried: Let $A: $ first ball is red and $B: $ second ball is red.

So $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$

Here $\displaystyle P(A)=\frac{2}{6}\times 1=\frac{1}{3}$

And $\displaystyle P(A\cap B)=\frac{2}{6}\times \frac{1}{5}=\frac{1}{15}$

I did not understand. How do I solve $P(B)$? Help me please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
P(B) &= P(A \cap B) + P(A^c \cap B)\\
&= P(A \cap B) + \frac{6}{8} \cdot\frac{2}{7}
\end{align}

Also, $P(A) = \frac{2}{2+6}$.

We do not have to compute $P(A \cap B)$ as it will cancel out.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't know what the first ball was, the second ball is just a uniformly random ball so the probability of $B$ is still $\frac13$.

If you don't find this convincing, you can check by considering the two possibilities: if $B$ occurs either both balls are red (probability $\frac1{15}$ as you already have) or the first ball is black and the second red (probability $\frac46\times \frac25=\frac{4}{15}$) so the total is $\frac5{15}$.

[edit: as Siong Thye Goh points out, the calculation in the question of $1/3$ is incorrect because there are $6$ black balls, not $6$ total balls.]

Answer (score 2):

They are asking you to calculate the probability of the following cases:

$$\{RB,BR,RR\}$$

thus simply

$$1-\frac{6}{8}\times \frac{5}{7}+=\frac{13}{28}$$

that is the complement of $\mathbb{P}\{BB\}$

Answer (score 1):

Let A : First Ball is Red
B: Second Ball is Red.

You need to find:
$ P(A) P(B|A) + P(A)P(B^c | A) + P(A^c)P(B | A^c)$

These are respectively the probabilities for RR,RB,BR

Answer (score 1):

> > A bag contains 2 red and 6 black balls.
>
> I did not understand. How do I solve P(B)?

Each individual ball has the same chance to be the first ball drawn.   *Two* among those *eight* are red.

Each individual ball has the same chance to be the second ball drawn.   *Two* among those *eight* are red.

The probability for obtaining two from two red balls when selecting two from eight balls is $\tbinom 22/\tbinom82$.

$\mathsf P(A)=1/4, \mathsf P(B)=1/4, \mathsf P(A\cap B)=1/28$ $$\mathsf P(A\cup B)=\dfrac{13}{28}$$

---

The probability for obtaining two from six black balls when selecting two from eight balls is $\tbinom 62/\tbinom 82$

$$\mathsf P((A\cup B)^\complement)=\dfrac{15}{28}$$